# How to always display when user is locked?

Tags: login

When using faillock and other common menthods to prevent password brute force, how to display to the user that the account is locked on all attempts (`login`, `su`, `sudo`, `doas`, `pam`, etc)?

I feel not showing that important information to a user legitimately trying to recall their password after returning from vacation or something is detrimental to the whole process. A correct password will now be shown to be incorrect to them and cause much more trouble.

Comment: Note that if you do that, you'll allow anyone a way to find out whether or not a particular account *exists* on your system. That, in itself, can be useful information for an attacker, enabling social engineering or other types of attacks. You may decide that the user convenience is worth the information leak risk for you, but you should be aware of the risk.

Comment: You have a policy of locking out users who do not authenticate themselves appropriately. It seems this policy is working, and what you find "detrimental" is part of its intended effect. Instead of making the systems less secure by showing internal information to unauthenticated users, I would suggest reversing the policy of locking users out.  Personal opinion: Locking a user's account based on failed login attempts allows disgruntled/bored coworkers to lock out everyone they know the username of.

Comment: In case you refer to the *pam_faillock* module with the *silent* option set, you could probably delete this option.

Comment: @telcoM if you worry about people probing for accounts on my ttys, or locally via accounts that can run sudo etc, i'd probably create a few thousand bogus accounts which won't ever login. The lockdown makes it a low target by making brute force harder even if you know the accounts.

Comment: @Kusalananda what you describe is a very bad work environment, you can't improve it with tech. The lockdown is just to make bruteforce prohibitive.

Comment: @gcb Absolutely correct. I should have made it clearer that I'm not in favour of password lockout schemes. In an ideal working environment, one shouldn't need to enforce lockouts of this type, nor have forced password rotations, or password quality checks of any type.  May I ask who would do the bruteforcing in your scenario?

Comment: @Kusalananda mostly a worry for stolen devices.

Comment: Like I said: you decide if the risk is applicable to your specific situation or not. I just wanted to ensure you know the default of not leaking any information to outsiders is a carefully considered design, and the most important reasons for it, so that your decision will be an informed one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like `fail2ban`.   From their own documentation:

> Fail2Ban scans log files like /var/log/auth.log and bans IP addresses conducting too many failed login attempts. It does this by updating system firewall rules to reject new connections from those IP addresses, for a configurable amount of time.

I'm not sure if it works for all login methods, but works great for `ssh` sessions.  What it does (by default) is bans specific IP addresses from authenticating.  The ban period depends on how many failed logins have occurred.  As the attacks persist, the ban period gets longer.  This reduces the number of attempts the attacker can make.

Assuming your user comes back from vacation (or is still on vacation), they should be able to login because their IP hasn't been banned.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question of how to tell the remote user that their account is locked.

Comment: Based on the comments to the original post, OP may be asking an XY-problem.  This is a Y solution.  I could delete this answer, but I feel like making OP aware of how others tackle the problem is only a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in a comment by @MC68020

remove `silent` from `/etc/security/faillock.conf` or any file in `/etc/pam.d/` and the lockdown messages will show up on most places.

But, as also noted on comments by @TelcoM, this might expose valid user names on the system.